# Android Game using drawable folders how?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I'm new at Android Game Development I already read (Dummies Android Game..., Sams Teach..).
I want to draw now several images (tiles) to create my map, but I also want that they are automatically scaled to the device screen as good as possible. At the moment I just know how to use images from folder drawable but they are not scaled to the screen...

I already saw some examples where they use xml files to get to images over R.id.... but for this I must use the xml as layout in the code and can't use something like this or?

```
 //create the view object
    view = new SurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(view);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

I'm a little bit confused... :(

How do other Game Programmer scale their images to the different device screens?

I would be very thankful for some examples!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `xml` for drawables these are located to the `drawable/` folder and not the `layout/` folder.

In order to use them you call `R.drawable.name_of_your_drawable` not `R.id....` nor `R.layout....`.

Another way to avoid blurring in larger screens is to provide different resources for different screen dpis for this option you have to place your drawables to

- `drawable-mdpi/`
- `drawable-hdpi/`
- `drawable-xhdpi/`
- etc

***Note:*** that when you use multiple folders each drawable must have the exact name in all folders and the system decides which to pick.

Answer (score 2):

You could let android scale the images for you automatically, but of course, the quality might not turn out the way you want, but it is less work on your part. If you want more control over the scaling of your images, the only choice is to manually create them and put them in their respective folders including the default folder (drawable folder without subfix), `drawble-mdpi` is for medium Dot-Per-Inch devices, such devices as 320x480 screen.

`drawable-hdpi` is the drawable folder for devices with a high density screen size such as 480x800 or 480x854 depending on the screen sizes as well. I am going to give you the threshold by which you use to tell if it is mdpi or hdpi so on

1.mdpi: 160dpi (dpi = Dot Per Inch, it is different from dp or dip which stands for density-independent pixel)

2. hdpi: 240dpi
3. xhpdi: 320dpi = 2 times mdpi, this includes devices such as galaxy s4 with a screen resolution of 1080x1900 depending on the screen sizes as well, you kinda get the idea of how big xhdpi is.
4. xxhpdi: 480dpi, this one is newer but you can be guaranteed xhdpi images will scale up to fit xxhdpi very nicely, generally, you dont need to create graphics assets for xxhdpi, xhdpi is good enough.

One rule you should remember is that, you should create images for xhdpi devices and scale down accordingly, not the other way around.

As for R.id.., the part after the "R" is called the resource type you want to reference, if it an id you put R.id, drawable use R.drawable, as in the `setContentView()` method, you have R.layout because you are referencing a layout resource. I hope this helps you a little

Comment: You're welcome, if you are new to android, I recommend checking the tutorial from Google here [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html), if you find it hard to follow, that's fine, I sometimes do too since I am a beginner. But I strongly discourage you from reading any series published by Sams Teach, especially their "in 24h" series, very very difficult to understand when you are a beginner, I used to want to quit learning programming because I thought it was too hard, which is true indeed, when I read their book at the time. But it is your choice though.